# How to use Sub Query with IBM Informix 10.0

Tags: sql, informix

RDBMS is INFORMIX 10.0

```
SELECT owner FROM systables WHERE TABNAME= ' VERSION';
```

Returns  9.50C1 (which equates to version 10.x)

The Sub Query works just fine:

```
SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id;
```

I want to use this Query as a Sub Query.

> **So my question is:**
>
> How do I get this done on IBM INFORMIX v10.0?
> Should be simple and straight forward right?

Any attempt to use that query as a Sub Query generates this meaningful message:

"Failed queries => 2"

INFORMIX - No "WITH" clause so this will not work:

```
WITH issuer_accts AS
(
SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id
)
SELECT issuer_accts.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM issuer_accts
GROUP BY issuer_accts.issuer_id;
```

Attempt to follow this example [(IBM documentation):](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_176.htm)

```
SELECT issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id
) issuer_accts
GROUP BY issuer_id;
```

Attempt to follow this example [(specific to INFORMIX v10.0)](http://informix-technology.blogspot.com/2007/06/cheetah-spot-by-spot-derived-tables-in.html)

```
SELECT issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
TABLE(MULTISET(
SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id
)) 
GROUP BY issuer_id;
```

Comment: Note that Informix 10.00 is a long time out of support.  Ideally, you should be upgrading to a more recent version — at this stage, that should be 12.10 (in years past, it might have been 11.10, 11.50 or 11.70 instead, but only 11.70 is a theoretical option now and should not be chosen).

Comment: Note that even 12.10 does not support the WITH clause.  Using a syntax diagram from 12.10 with a 10.00 server is not guaranteed to lead to happiness — you need the 10.00 manuals, which are available from https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039629, a page which documents that 10.00 reached EOS (end of service) in 2010.

Comment: What tool are you using that generates the `Failed queries => 2` message?  I don't recall ever seeing that, which may just mean I'm lucky.

Comment: In your attempted WITH query, you have `WITH accts AS ( … ) SELECT issuer_accts.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM issuer_accts …` — presumably, that should be `WITH issuer_accts` (not that it makes any difference to whether it works with Informix).

Comment: In your third attempt, you have a semicolon at the end of the inner query (the sub-query); that should categorically be deleted.  The previous attempts also have the same problem, though there also other reasons that they fail.  That unwanted semicolon probably accounts for the '2 queries failed' error message, since it marks the end of the (first) statement, and the `)) 
GROUP BY issuer_id;` part is the second  — meaning that there are two syntactically incorrect queries on show.  Try the third option again without that semicolon — all other things being equal, that should work.

Comment: As a general comment, it would be helpful to create outline (minimal) schemas for the tables mentioned, and supply a few rows of data for each, plus the desired output from the sample tables.  This is part of what it takes to create the database equivalent of an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thanks responding: I am using IBM Data Studio on the client side (Eclipse) and I confirmed that the Informix version is 10.  I fixed the syntax errors.  Removing the semi-colon still generates  this error:  "A syntax error has occurred."  But the real limiting factor is the RDBMS version.

Comment: I no longer have ready access to 10.00 (or 11.10 or 11.50), though I still have the manuals for many of the older versions.  I can usually get 11.70 or 12.10.  A direct approach looks likely to be preferable to the alternatives anyway, though it would be nice if the server supported the variations you wanted to use and transformed it to the direct approach.  The query optimizers often get pretty close to that, but only when they recognize the syntax you specify.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought I could solve the problem with the following SQL but the true unique key is the combination of all 3 fields: acct, bin, issuer.  So I still need a way to generate the correct set before I COUNT:  SELECT prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY prod.issuer_id;

Comment: This is where the MCVE comes in.  I'm having difficulty visualizing what the data might look like and the result you want.  Please edit the question (you can always do that) and show outline schemas, sample data, and desired results from the sample data.  If you've got a query that nearly works, show its output too, and explain what's wrong with it, using the sample data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this early version of Informix v10 does not support "Sub Query"/"Inline Query"/"Inner Query" then the conventional practice is to use TEMP tables to support complex sql statements.  Therefore this is the working answer for this version v10 of IBM Informix:

```
SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM fund_acct AS acct
JOIN products AS prod ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx'
AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id
INTO TEMP temp_issuer_accts WITH NO LOG;

SELECT issuer_id, COUNT(*) account_count
FROM temp_issuer_accts
GROUP BY issuer_id;

DROP TABLE temp_issuer_accts;
```

Temp tables survive only for the duration of the session - so make sure your connection remains open over the execution of multiple statements.

Relevant reference here:

[INTO TEMP clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1066.htm)

[Using the WITH NO LOG option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0575.htm)

[Explicit inserts with SELECT...INTO TEMP statements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_583.htm)

[Duration of temporary tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0583.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need an alias:

```
SELECT issuer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM fund_acct AS acct JOIN
           products AS prod
           ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
      WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx' AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
      GROUP BY acct.fund_acct_nbr, acct.bin, prod.issuer_id
     ) x
GROUP BY issuer_id;
```

But, under most reasonable assumptions about the data, you could also phrase this as:

```
SELECT issuer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT acct.bin || ' ' || prod.issuer_id)
FROM fund_acct AS acct JOIN
     products AS prod
     ON acct.cusip = prod.cusip
WHERE prod.issuer_id = 'xxxx' AND SUBSTR(acct.bin, 1, 1) = 'x'
GROUP BY issuer_id;
```

Comment: I did actually try that variation (and tried it again just to be sure) but it still generates the same error:  "Failed queries => 2".  I also tried your alternative suggestion but it produces this message:  "A sytax error has occurred."

Comment: The `FROM (SELECT …)` notation was added to Informix during the 11.x release series — probably 11.50.  It won't work in Informix 10.00.

Comment: The first query would need the semicolon after `prod.issuer_id` in the inner GROUP BY clause removed.  However, even though that would make it work (or, at least, would give it a decent chance of working) in current versions of Informix, it probably wouldn't help with such an old version as 10.00 which doesn't support 'sub-queries in the FROM clause'.